# AWS EC-2 check the domain is linked correctly with the public IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, devops

I have an EC-2 Instance and a domain name. I've added A record and couple of CNAME records in DNS management service where I bought the domain name. I've put my AWS instance's Public IP address as the value in those records. I want to know how can I check that domain is now correctly linked or not to the my instance?

I mean if there is a way to check that domain is succesfully linked with my instance. I know then there is no problem with domain selling guys and I only need to check with nginx and AWS settings to debug issues.

How do I know this?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `ping` command from your terminal or command line if you are in windows.

```
[noones@noones ~]$ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.203.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bom07s11-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.203.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=53.0 ms
64 bytes from bom07s11-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.203.174): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=51.1 ms
```

you will see your ec2 instance ip address on ping response. As we are seeing `216.58.203.174` on above `google.com` domain

Comment: To do this I have to host the app in the AWS? Because right now I didn't host anything on AWS. I need to make sure all good with the DNS before I move to the AWS thing.

Comment: You don't have to host anything on ec2

Answer (score 0):

To check whether your DNS is completely resolved use Dnschecker sites.

If it is resolved and still you're not able to reach your site. Kindly go through nginx logs in `var/log/nginxlogs` and also check you're having proper nginx configurations